# Execute result from subquery in a merge into statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query that has as the output the following table (2 columns). What it means, is that I'm going to use the result to wrap it inside a merge into statement.

```
INSERT_COLUMNS          UPDATE_COLUMNS
BANK_NAME               target.BANK_NAME = source.BANKNAME
```

What I'm talking about is this:

```
with sql_prepare_merge as (
SELECT *
FROM another_table
),

MERGE INTO bank_raw AS target
    USING bank AS source
        ON source.id = target.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET (select update_columns from sql_prepare_merge)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (select insert_columns from sql_prepare_merge)
        VALUES (source.id, (select insert_columns from sql_prepare_merge));
```

Keep in mind that the "sql_prepare_merge" is the name from the CTE where I'm getting the table I shared with you - and it has much more code in it, but they don't help here. So, I'm planning to take the text resulting from the subquery and insert it inside the merge statement.

So far, the error I'm getting is: `syntax error line 19 at position 4 unexpected 'WHEN'.`. By the way, this is inside Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible as per my understanding of the docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#notmatchedclause-for-inserts

In the non matched clause for inserts you can specify only such values/expressions,  refer to the source relations. This means you somehow need to adjust your source part itself (e.g. by joining the initial source with another_table). If this is not possible, you would need to go for separate INSERT and UPDATE statements.